# Odd PS3 Problem Error Number 80710092

Tags: ps3, psn

I am currently without regular, sustained, access to a computer. This is forcing me to use my PS3 much like one, namely for surfing the interweb. I'm also a regular on Spacebattles, which some of you may know of. Today, while trying to access Spacebattles I received the Error 80710092. Now, being an individual with access to Google I proceeded to look it up. Nearly every result is invalid for my problem, relating directly to loss of connection to PSN. I have connection to PSN and I have internet, clearly. What I don't have is access to Spacebattles. Does anyone know why I'm getting this very peculiar error, in particular, how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe you aren't losing connection to PSN and their servers, but to the Spacebattle servers? I don't know if they are separate, though, as I don't play it and also don't have a PS3.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Spacebattles is a forum but I know I'm not losing connection to their servers as that returns a very different, and frustratingly familiar, error.